# How can I share control of a web app?

Tags: sharing, access-control

Is it possible to share control of a web app over multiple computers? To be clear, I do not control the web app! For example, suppose I had a turn-based game that was supposed to be played hotseat. It would be nice to be able to take your turn on one computer then to pass control of the web app to another person to take their turn.

I understand that getting this working flawlessly with a generic web app would be very difficult, but are there any solutions that work with a reasonable subset of applications? I'd like any solutions to preferably be cross-platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are looking for a Tool or You want to develop a hack by your self which can give you this kind of control. If you are looking for a tool then http://www.webex.com/ can do wonders for you. In this you can share not only your entire desktop but also individual app. In this App can be seen by all but only 1 person has control over it. Then that person can assign someone else a control.

If you are talking about creating your own solution then look into Rich Internet Applications built in Flash or Silver light.

Comment: Thanks, web ex looks pretty cool - although, since it is Cisco, it'll be horribly expensive. I wonder if there are any alternatives

Comment: See if this works for you http://www.voip-sol.com/top-5-webex-alternatives/ ....here is another good free options http://www.mikogo.com/

Answer (score 0):

What about using a remote desktop solution like [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx)? This will allow both people to control one computer (and thus, one web browser and one website instance).

The disadvantage is that you can't control it at the same time (you'll have to coordinate mouse and keyboard use, as if the computer had two mice and two keyboards connected).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a **load balancer** will help? I assume you want to switch to machine B if machine A fails (both are running the same app)?

Comment: Load balancers are for developers. I am trying to find a way of sharing a web app so that people on multiple computers can use the same instance of the app

Answer (score -1):

Okay,this is my solution,untested but i learnt from looking at omegle.com,the clone anyway.To play the game,a user must be logged in(sessions),and after user A plays,the information is logged to a database via ajax,and you can use this information to know whose turn it is.Load balancing plays a huge role here too.

From omegle:

```
<!-- Yes, I'm using frames as a load balancing measure. Yes, I know
         this is horrible, insane, absurd, ridiculous, stupid, and
         broken. It's just a temporary stop-gap measure, though. --> 
    <frameset cols="100%"> 
        <frame src="http://bajor.omegle.com/"> 
    </frameset>
```

Comment: This question is not about the developer of an app enabling multiple people to share control of a web app, but about someone with no association to it trying to hack together a way of getting it to work

Comment: Unless the game allows multiple players,i don't see how what you ask is possible and if it is,it will involve a great deal of hacking and this is why.A web app which you do not control uses cookies and sharing cookies across a network in an app you do not control is very hard if not impossible.However you could checkout this https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib/pull/15 rails project.

Comment: I know it is hard, but I would be surprised if a partial solution were not possible